# What is 'awesomium_process.exe'?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have noticed that I have an erroneous process running that is *apparently* related to Guild Wars 2 called `awesomium_process.exe`. This seems to be launched along with the Guild Wars 2 executable from a folder `%TEMP%\gw2cache-{4E8E6364-ABBF-1665-6763-8E4EBFAB6516}` and does not appear to actually be 'installed' on my PC in the Guild Wars 2 folder.

Is this spyware? If this is official why is it installed like spyware/trojans/viruses rather than being installed into the Guild Wars 2 installation folder?

Does this *have* to be running, and can it be disabled/removed?

What is the purpose of this process?

Comment: I think it's used by ArenaNet to render the Trading Post and load w/e other [web pages the game needs](http://awesomium.com/).

Comment: yeah I did some research due to its spyware-like behaviour, just wanted to be sure...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `awesomium_process.exe` is a lightweight web browser based on Webkit, that is used by several games (including Guild Wars 2 and Lord of the Rings Online). In Guild Wars 2 specifically, it is used for the Black Lion trading post screens (Gem Store, Currency Exchange, Trading Post, etc).

Killing the process will result in the process being relaunched the next time you visit any of these screens. Preventing the process from running at all will result in these screens simply not working anymore.

Deleting the executable will result in it being recreated the next time the game is started.

The official website for Awesomium is [awesomium.com](http://awesomium.com/).

A discussion on Guild Wars 2 Guru regarding this process can be found [here](http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/56136-awesomium-processexe32/).

Comment: It does look pretty suspicious and has previously been [flagged by](http://support.awesomium.com/discussions/problems/106-virus-checkers-detecting-awesomiumprocessexe-as-malicious) certain A/V programs.

Comment: @Krazer but don't leave out the 2nd half of the story, it was a false positive (And only by Norton) and ever seance they started signing the exe it no longer shows up as a false positive.

Comment: It's also found in TSW.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in Garry's Mod addons file, it only opens when I'm playing the game, and doesn't seem to be harmful, but if you try to close it via task manager, it reopens in a few seconds to prevent the game from shutting down.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question's already been answered; is there any way you could expand on yours to provide more info?